# C++ Implementing SFML InputStream

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to implement a custom InputStream but I'm having trouble doing so.

I seem to be opening the zip file just fine, and the library I'm using (https://bitbucket.org/wbenny/ziplib/wiki/Home) automatically gives me an istream* to the 
data.

Yet I keep failing when I try to load the image file texture with the stream through:

`sf::Texture::loadFromStream(sf::InputStream)`

Any ideas as to what I'm doing incorrectly?

[sf::InputStream](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.2/classsf_1_1InputStream.php)

[sf::Texture::loadFromStream](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.2/classsf_1_1Texture.php#a6803a13465a7113a8964d1081841886d)

Here's my implementation:

Header)

```
#include <ZipFile.h>

namespace lvn
{
    class NStream : public sf::InputStream
    {
    private:
        ZipArchiveEntry::Ptr m_entry;
        std::shared_ptr<std::istream> m_File = nullptr;
        std::string m_filename;
        //bool m_file_is_open = false;

    public:
        static bool ReadTxtFile( std::string filepath, tstring& textbuffer );

        NStream( std::string pathName="" );

        virtual ~NStream();

        bool isOpen() const;

        bool open( std::string pathName );

        void close();

        virtual sf::Int64 read( void* data, sf::Int64 size );

        virtual sf::Int64 seek( sf::Int64 position );

        virtual sf::Int64 tell();

        virtual sf::Int64 getSize();

    };
}
```

CPP)

```
#include <ZipFile.h>
#include "NStream.h"

namespace lvn
{
    NStream::NStream( std::string pathName )
        //: m_File( 0x00 )
    {
        using namespace std;
        open( pathName );
    }

    NStream::~NStream( )
    {
        close( );
    }

    bool NStream::isOpen( ) const
    {
        //return (m_File != 0x0);
        return ( m_File != nullptr );
    }

    //Ex. Images//albert.png
    bool NStream::open( std::string pathName )
    {
        using namespace std;
        close( );
        auto archive_name = pathName.substr( 0, pathName.find( "/" ) ) + (".vndat"); //need to add the archive extension to the name

        ZipArchive::Ptr archive = ZipFile::Open( archive_name );
        m_entry = archive->GetEntry( pathName );
        if ( m_entry == nullptr )
            return false;

        m_File = make_shared<istream>( nullptr );
        m_File->rdbuf( m_entry->GetDecompressionStream()->rdbuf() );
        m_filename = pathName;

        return isOpen( );
    }

    void NStream::close( )
    {
        m_File.reset( );
    }

    sf::Int64 NStream::read( void* data, sf::Int64 size )
    {
        if ( !isOpen( ) )
            return -1;

        auto posPrev = tell();
        m_File->read( static_cast<char *>( data ), size );
        auto cur = tell();

        return tell() - posPrev;
    }

    sf::Int64 NStream::seek( sf::Int64 position )
    {
        if ( !isOpen( ) )
            return -1;

        m_File->seekg( position );
        return tell( );
    }

    sf::Int64 NStream::tell( )
    {
        if ( !isOpen( ) )
            return -1;

        // istream returns the offset in bytes or -1 on error just like SFML wants.
        return m_File->tellg( );
    }

    sf::Int64 NStream::getSize( )
    {
        if ( !isOpen( ) )
            return -1;

        //get length of file (by seeking to end), then restore original offset
        const auto originalIdx = tell( );
        m_File->seekg( 0, m_File->end );
        const sf::Int64 length = tell( );
        seek( originalIdx );

        // tell returns length of file or -1 on error just like SFML wants.
        return length;
    }
}
```

Example usage (should work but doesn't: loadFromStream fails):

```
auto pTextureStream = make_shared<NStream>();
pTextureStream->open( "Images/image.png" );
auto pTexture = make_shared<sf::Texture>();
pTexture->loadFromStream( *pTextureStream );
```

Comment: Where are you calling `loadFromStream()`?

Comment: @JamesMoore Thanks for the comment, just added an example to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation, I hope you find it useful

```
class  StreamSFML : public sf::InputStream
{
    std::shared_ptr<std::istream> m_source;

public:
    explicit StreamSFML(std::shared_ptr<std::istream> stream) : m_source(stream) {}

    sf::Int64 read(void* data, sf::Int64 size) override
    {
        m_source->read(static_cast<char*>(data), size);

        return m_source->gcount();
    }
    sf::Int64 seek(sf::Int64 position) override
    {
        m_source->seekg(position, m_source->beg);

        return m_source->gcount();
    }
    sf::Int64 tell() override
    {
        return m_source->tellg();
    }
    sf::Int64 getSize() override
    {
        auto curr = m_source->tellg();

        m_source->seekg(0, m_source->end);
        sf::Int64 pos = static_cast<sf::Int64>(m_source->tellg());

        m_source->seekg(curr, m_source->beg);

        return pos;
    }

};
```